# Get observable notebook metadata

Tags: javascript, fetch, observablehq

I'm trying to build a "preview card" to link an observable notebook:
- preview image
- title 
- description

is there an api that can be used to do this? I have tried to use `https://api.observablehq.com/document/{user}/{notebook}@latest`, but it is referrer protected.

Also tried fetching the html and parsing the meta headers, but can only get an opaque response via `no-cors`.

This implementation is a static website that will be linking directly to the notebooks, so a server to parse the page is off the table.

Comment: There is not currently a public API with CORS headers, though this is a common request; you can upvote the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/observablehq/feedback/issues/6. It is possible to use the private internal API you noted on a static site through a CORS proxy, and you can tinker with that, but that's an unsupported approach, liable to break when we change the (unversioned) internal API.